# $rootScope doesn't update in the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

In my controller

```
$rootScope.products = []
$rootScope.forCheckout = []

//I initialize the $rootScope.products and has values

$scope.add = function() {
    //Some code


    // This updates forCheckout
    myService.function(); 
}
```

In the view

```
<div ng-repeat="items in products">
  {{item.attribute}}

  <button ng-click="add()"></button>

</div>
```

// This at first is empty. When I click the button it updates the $rootScope.forCheckout but nothing changes in the view

```
<div ng-repeat="items in forCheckout">
   {{item.name}}
</div>
```

My view doesn't update forCheckout but the actual $rootScope.forCheckout is changed on my console.

I've tried

```
setTimeout(function() {
   $rootScope.$apply();
},1000)
```

but nothing changed...

Comment: Have you injected $rootScope?

Comment: Both in controller and in service. No errors or warnings on my console at all.

Comment: Can you show your controller and service? I think you are getting data from service which is **$http** call.

Comment: I fill the $rootScope.products after $http call. Then, when I hit add button I call a function which actually checks which of products have .quantity > 0 and pushes it in the $rootScope.forCheckout. Nothing is asynchronous for $rootScope.forCheckout.

Comment: Can you provide your Plunkr of actual problem?

Comment: Created a small fiddle here on what I think you're trying to achieve.  Btw, $rootScope is not the way to go about this.  https://jsfiddle.net/ybwwe4Lh/

Comment: This is exactly what I need to do but I am new in angular and haven't learned to work with services to share data between controllers and views yet. So I have chosen $rootScope because I need to have access in data from other controllers as well. Is there any way to make it work with my implementation ?

Comment: @Korte I updated my fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/ybwwe4Lh/) to provide an example of sharing data between controllers.

Comment: @rob thank you ! I appreciate it.